# Restricted Three-Body Problem

Tags: calculus, reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, classical-mechanics

The movement of a spacecraft between Earth and the Moon is an example of the infamous Three Body Problem. It is said that a general analytical solution for TBP is not known because of the complexity of solving the effect of three bodies which all pull on each other while moving, a total of six interactions. Mathematician Richard Arenstorf while at NASA solved a special case of this problem, by simplifying the interactions to four, because, the effect of the spacecraft's gravity upon the motion of the vastly more massive Earth and Moon is practically non-existent. Arenstorf found a stable orbit for a spacecraft orbiting between the Earth and Moon, shaped like an '8'

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Arenstorf

Was Arenstorf's solution purely analytical, or did he use numerical mechanisms? Is the '8' shape an optimal path, meaning the route on which the spacecraft would expand the least amount of energy? If yes, how was this requirement included in the derivation in mathematical form?

If anyone has a clean derivation for this problem, that would be great, or any links to books, other papers, etc.

Note: Apparently there was an earlier related mathoverflow question on this as well:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52489/on-the-non-rigorous-calculations-of-the-trajectories-in-the-moon-landings

Arenstorf's technical report is here

http://hdl.handle.net/2060/19630005545

Regards,

Comment: Arenstorf actually found his orbits through numerics. There's a short discussion in Hairer/Norsett/Wanner with references. I'll post it if nobody beats me to it...

Comment: he used numerics.. interesting. thanks. Hairer/Norsett/Wanner discussion would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm far away from my notes, so it might take me a while to write something. :( I was about to suggest looking at Fehlberg's "Runge-kutta type formulas of high-order accuracy and their application to the numerical integration of the restricted problem of three bodies" but there seems to be no digital copy of that available. Additionally, there's related work (in German) by Filippi that should interest you as well.

Comment: ... but let me distract you with [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MNa0w.png) and [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRPw0.png) in the meantime...

Comment: See also this question's [crossposting to MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71725/restricted-three-body-problem).

Comment: This was [crossposted to MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71725). In the future, please wait some time before posting your question in multiple fora, and when you do, provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to see hear from you that you'd already gotten the solution elsewhere.

Comment: See [this](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2373181) as well...

Comment: Arenstorf's paper linked by @J.M. is freely available at [NASA](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19630005545).

Comment: @j-m-is-not-a-mathematician BTW, the Hairer book does not seem to talk about how Arenstorf found the initial values for the IVP - if you or anyone knows that answer, please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670728/finding-the-right-initial-conditions-for-a-three-body-problem-periodic-solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the comments, you were already informed that numerics had to be used so I will explain from that point on.

The figure 8 design isn't because it is an optimal path. It occurs due to the gravity of moon and the Earth. When the spacecraft comes within the sphere of influence (SOI) of the moon, the spacecraft is pulled towards it. If the spacecraft is moving at escape velocity, the moon will perturb the flight but the spacecraft won't do a fly by. With the current speed, the moon's gravity is enough to cause an orbital fly by. Upon exiting the moon's SOI, the spacecraft is being pulled in by the Earth. Since the trajectory of the fly by was throwing the spacecraft away from the moon, it crosses its original path but this is short lived since the Earth then pulls it back in. If the spacecraft would have picked up enough velocity from the orbital maneuver to be on a parabolic or hyperbolic trajectory, it could have escaped the pull of Earth and been sent out into space.

One way to determine test speeds in designing a flight is to find the Jacobi constant, $C$. For a given $C$, the zero velocity curves are determined. Since we wanted to reach the moon, $C\geq -1.6649$ which corresponds to an initial velocity of at least $10.85762$ but a velocity of $11.01$ is the required escape velocity from the Earth so the initial speed has to be less than $v_{esc}$.

---

We can derive the equations of motion only up to a point. I am skipping the basic derivation of the two body problem so we can move on to the crux of the matter. 
\begin{alignat*}{4} 
  r_{12} & = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2} & \qquad & x_1
  &&{}= \text{Is the } x \text{ location of } m_1\\
  x_2 & = x_1 + r_{12} & & &&{}\phantom{=}
  \text{relative to the center of gravity.}\\
  x_1 & = \frac{-m_2}{m_1 + m_2}r_{12} & & \pi_1 &&{}=
  \frac{m_1}{m_1 + m_2}\\
  x_2 & = \frac{m_1}{m_1 + m_2}r_{12} & & \pi_2 &&{}=
  \frac{m_2}{m_1 + m_2}\\
  0 & = m_1x_1 + m_2x_2
\end{alignat*}
We can describe the position of $m$ as
$\mathbf{r} = x\hat{\mathbf{i}} + y\hat{\mathbf{j}} + z\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ in relation to the center of gravity, i.e., the origin.
\begin{align} 
  \mathbf{r}_1
  & =  (x - x_1)\hat{\mathbf{i}} + y\hat{\mathbf{j}} +
    z\hat{\mathbf{k}}\\
  & = (x + \pi_2r_{12})\hat{\mathbf{i}} + y\hat{\mathbf{j}}
    + z\hat{\mathbf{k}}\tag{1}\\
  \mathbf{r}_2
  & =  (x - x_2)\hat{\mathbf{i}} + y\hat{\mathbf{j}} +
    z\hat{\mathbf{k}}\\
  & = (x - \pi_1r_{12})\hat{\mathbf{i}} + y\hat{\mathbf{j}}
    + z\hat{\mathbf{k}}\tag{2}
\end{align}
Let's define the absolute acceleration where $\omega$ is the initial angular
velocity which is constant.
Then $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$.
$$ 
\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_{\text{abs}}
= \mathbf{a}_{\text{rel}} + \mathbf{a}_{\text{CG}}
+ \mathbf{\varOmega}\times(\mathbf{\varOmega}\times\mathbf{r})
+ \dot{\mathbf{\varOmega}}\times\mathbf{r}
+ 2\mathbf{\varOmega}\times\mathbf{v}_{\text{rel}}
\tag{3}
$$
where
\begin{alignat*}{4}
  \mathbf{a}_{\text{rel}}
  & = \text{Rectilinear acceleration relative to the frame} & \quad &
  \mathbf{\varOmega}\times(\mathbf{\varOmega}\times\mathbf{r}) &&{}= 
  \text{Centripetal acceleration}\\
  2\mathbf{\varOmega}\times\mathbf{v}_{\text{rel}} & =
  \text{Coriolis acceleration}
\end{alignat*}
Since the velocity of the center of gravity is constant,
$\mathbf{a}_{\text{CG}} = 0$, and $\dot{\mathbf{\varOmega}} = 0$ since the
angular velocity of a circular orbit is constant.
Therefore, $(3)$ becomes:
$$ 
\ddot{\mathbf{r}} = \mathbf{a}_{\text{rel}}
+ \mathbf{\varOmega}\times(\mathbf{\varOmega}\times\mathbf{r})
+ 2\mathbf{\varOmega}\times\mathbf{v}_{\text{rel}}
\tag{4}
$$
where
\begin{align} 
  \mathbf{\varOmega} & = \varOmega\hat{\mathbf{k}}\tag{5}\\
  \mathbf{r} & = x\hat{\mathbf{i}} + y\hat{\mathbf{j}}
               + z\hat{\mathbf{k}}\tag{6}\\
  \dot{\mathbf{r}} & = \mathbf{v}_{\text{CG}}
                     + \mathbf{\varOmega}\times\mathbf{r}
                     + \mathbf{v}_{\text{rel}}\tag{7}\\
  \mathbf{v}_{\text{rel}} & = \dot{x}\hat{\mathbf{i}}
                            + \dot{y}\hat{\mathbf{j}}
                            + \dot{z}\hat{\mathbf{k}}\tag{8}\\
  \mathbf{a}_{\text{rel}} & = \ddot{x}\hat{\mathbf{i}}
                            + \ddot{y}\hat{\mathbf{j}}
                            + \ddot{z}\hat{\mathbf{k}}\tag{9}
\end{align}
After substituting $(5)$, $(6)$, $(8)$, and
$(9)$ into $(3)$, we obtain
$$
\ddot{\mathbf{r}} =
\left(\ddot{x} - 2\varOmega\dot{y} - \varOmega^2x\right)\hat{\mathbf{i}}
+ \left(\ddot{y} + 2\varOmega\dot{x} - \varOmega^2y\right)\hat{\mathbf{j}}
+ \ddot{z}\hat{\mathbf{k}}.
\tag{10}
$$
Newton's $2^{\text{nd}}$ Law of Motion is
$m\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{F}_1 + \mathbf{F}_2$ where
$\mathbf{F}_1 = -\frac{Gm_1m}{r_1^3}\mathbf{r}_1$ and
$\mathbf{F}_2 = -\frac{Gm_2m}{r_2^3}\mathbf{r}_2$.
Let $\mu_1 = Gm_1$ and $\mu_2 = Gm_2$.
\begin{align} 
  m\mathbf{a} & = \mathbf{F}_1 + \mathbf{F}_2\\
  m\mathbf{a} & = -\frac{m\mu_1}{r_1^3}\mathbf{r}_1
                - \frac{m\mu_2}{r_2^3}\mathbf{r}_2\\
  \mathbf{a} & = -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}\mathbf{r}_1
               - \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}\mathbf{r}_2\\
  \bigl(\ddot{x} - 2\varOmega\dot{y} - \varOmega^2x\bigr)\hat{\mathbf{i}}
  + \bigl(\ddot{y} + 2\varOmega\dot{x} - \varOmega^2y\bigr)\hat{\mathbf{j}}
  + \ddot{z}\hat{\mathbf{k}}
              & = -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}\mathbf{r}_1
                - \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}\mathbf{r}_2\\
  \bigl(\ddot{x} - 2\varOmega\dot{y} - \varOmega^2x\bigr)\hat{\mathbf{i}}
  + \bigl(\ddot{y} + 2\varOmega\dot{x} - \varOmega^2y\bigr)\hat{\mathbf{j}}
  + \ddot{z}\hat{\mathbf{k}}
              & =
                \begin{aligned}
                  - & \frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}\Bigl[(x +
                  \pi_2r_{12})\hat{\mathbf{i}} + \hat{\mathbf{j}} +
                  \hat{\mathbf{k}}\Bigr]\\
                  - & \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}\Bigl[(x -
                  \pi_1r_{12})\hat{\mathbf{i}} + \hat{\mathbf{j}} +
                  \hat{\mathbf{k}}\Bigr]
                \end{aligned}\tag{12}
\end{align}
Now all we have to do is equate the coefficients.
\begin{align}
  \ddot{x} - 2\varOmega\dot{y} - \varOmega^2x
  & = -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}(x + \pi_2r_{12}) - \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}(x
    - \pi_1r_{12})\\
  \ddot{y} + 2\varOmega\dot{x} - \varOmega^2y
  & = -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}y - \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}y\\
  \ddot{z}
  & = -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}z - \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}z
\end{align}
We now have system of nonlinear ODEs. We can assume the trajectory is in plane and we do that by letting $z = 0$ so we only have two equations remaining:
\begin{align}
  \ddot{x} - 2\varOmega\dot{y} - \varOmega^2x
  & = -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}(x + \pi_2r_{12}) - \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}(x
    - \pi_1r_{12})\\
  \ddot{y} + 2\varOmega\dot{x} - \varOmega^2y
  & = -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}y - \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}y
\end{align}
Now to achieve the require trajectory we can use the true anomaly of $-90^{\circ}$, a flight path angle of $20^{\circ}$, and an initial velocity of $v_0 = 10.9148$ km/s. At this point, we have no other choice but to numerically integrate. Here is a code that will achieve the desired plot. However, in the actually apollo flight, they had mid course corrections so they arrived exactly on the other side of Earth.

### Python

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython

import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.optimize import brentq
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import pylab

me = 5.974 * 10 ** 24  #  mass of the earth
mm = 7.348 * 10 ** 22  #  mass of the moon
G = 6.67259 * 10 ** -20  #  gravitational parameter
re = 6378.0  #  radius of the earth in km
rm = 1737.0  #  radius of the moon in km
r12 = 384400.0  #  distance between the CoM of the earth and moon
M = me + mm
d = 200  #  distance the spacecraft is above the Earth
pi2 = mm / M
mue = 398600.0  #  gravitational parameter of earth km^3/sec^2
mum = G * mm  #  grav param of the moon
omega = np.sqrt(mu / r12 ** 3)
vbo = 10.9148
nu = -np.pi*0.5
gamma = 20*np.pi/180.0  #  angle in radians of the flight path

vx = vbo * (np.sin(gamma) * np.cos(nu) - np.cos(gamma) * np.sin(nu))
#  velocity of the bo in the x direction
vy = vbo * (np.sin(gamma) * np.sin(nu) + np.cos(gamma) * np.cos(nu))
#  velocity of the bo in the y direction

xrel = (re + d)*np.cos(nu)-pi2*r12
#  spacecraft x location relative to the earth
yrel = (re + 200.0) * np.sin(nu)

u0 = [xrel, yrel, 0, vx, vy, 0]

def deriv(u, dt):
    return [u[3],  #  dotu[0] = u[3]
            u[4],  #  dotu[1] = u[4]
            u[5],  #  dotu[2] = u[5]
            (2 * omega * u[4] + omega ** 2 * u[0] - mue * (u[0] + pi2 * r12) /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] + pi2 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3) - mum *
             (u[0] - pi1 * r12) /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] - pi1 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3)),
            #  dotu[3] = that
            (-2 * omega * u[3] + omega ** 2 * u[1] - mue * u[1] /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] + pi2 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3) - mum * u[1] /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] - pi1 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3)),
            #  dotu[4] = that
            0]  #  dotu[5] = 0


dt = np.linspace(0.0, 535000.0, 535000.0)  #  secs to run the simulation
u = odeint(deriv, u0, dt)

x, y, z, x2, y2, z2 = u.T

# 3d plot
fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z, color = 'r')

# 2d plot if you want
#fig2 = pylab.figure(2)
#ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
#ax2.plot(x, y, color = 'r')

#  adding the moon
phi = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
xm = rm * np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta)) + r12 - pi2 * r12
ym = rm * np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
zm = rm * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(xm, ym, zm, color = '#696969', linewidth = 0)
ax.auto_scale_xyz([-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000])
#  adding the earth
xe = re * np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta)) - pi2 * r12
ye = re * np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
ze = re * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(xe, ye, ze, color = '#4169E1', linewidth = 0)
ax.auto_scale_xyz([-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000])

ax.set_xlim3d(-20000, 385000)
ax.set_ylim3d(-20000, 80000)
ax.set_zlim3d(-50000, 50000)

pylab.show()
```

[image]

### Matlab

script:

```
days = 24*3600;
G = 6.6742e-20;
rmoon = 1737;
rearth = 6378;
r12 = 384400;
m1 = 5974e21;
m2 = 7348e19;
M = m1 + m2;
pi_1 = m1/M;
pi_2 = m2/M;
mu1 = 398600;
mu2 = 4903.02;
mu = mu1 + mu2;
W = sqrt(mu/r12^3);
x1 = -pi_2*r12;
x2 = pi_1*r12;

d0 = 200;
phi = -90;
v0 = 10.9148;
gamma = 20;
t0 = 0;
tf = 6.2*days;
r0 = rearth + d0;
x = r0*cosd(phi) + x1;
y = r0*sind(phi);

vx = v0*(sind(gamma)*cosd(phi) - cosd(gamma)*sind(phi));
vy = v0*(sind(gamma)*sind(phi) + cosd(gamma)*cosd(phi));
f0 = [x; y; vx; vy];

[t,f] = rkf45(@rates, [t0 tf], f0);
x = f(:,1);
y = f(:,2);
vx = f(:,3);
vy = f(:,4);
xf = x(end);
yf = y(end);
vxf = vx(end);
vyf = vy(end);

df = norm([xf - x2, yf - 0]) - rmoon;
vf = norm([vxf, vyf]);

plot(x,y)
```

functions: 2 separate ones

```
function [tout, yout] = rkf45(ode_function, tspan, y0, tolerance)
a = [0 1/4 3/8 12/13 1 1/2];
b = [0 0 0 0 0
     1/4 0 0 0 0
     3/32 9/32 0 0 0
     1932/2197 -7200/2197 7296/2197 0 0
     439/216 -8 3680/513 -845/4104 0
     -8/27 2 -3544/2565 1859/4104 -11/40];
c4 = [25/216 0 1408/2565 2197/4104 -1/5 0];
c5 = [16/135 0 6656/12825 28561/56430 -9/50 2/55];
if nargin < 4
    tol = 1.e-8;
else
    tol = tolerance;
end
t0 = tspan(1);
tf = tspan(2);
t = t0;
y = y0;
tout = t;
yout = y';
h = (tf - t0)/100; % Assumed initial time step.

while t < tf
    hmin = 16*eps(t);
    ti = t;
    yi = y;
    for i = 1:6
        t_inner = ti + a(i)*h;
        y_inner = yi;
        for j = 1:i-1
            y_inner = y_inner + h*b(i,j)*f(:,j);
        end
        f(:,i) = feval(ode_function, t_inner, y_inner);
    end
    te = h*f*(c4' - c5');
    te_max = max(abs(te));
    ymax = max(abs(y));
    te_allowed = tol*max(ymax,1.0);
    delta = (te_allowed/(te_max + eps))^(1/5);
    if te_max <= te_allowed
        h = min(h, tf-t);
        t = t + h;
        y = yi + h*f*c5';
        tout = [tout;t];
        yout = [yout;y'];
    end
    h = min(delta*h, 4*h);
    if h < hmin
        fprintf(['\n\n Warning: Step size fell below its minimum\n'...
            ' allowable value (%g) at time %g.\n\n'], hmin, t)
        return
    end
end
```

second function:

```
function dfdt = rates(t,f)
r12 = 384400;
m1 = 5974e21;
m2 = 7348e19;
M = m1 + m2;
pi_1 = m1/M;
pi_2 = m2/M;
mu1 = 398600;
mu2 = 4903.02;
mu = mu1 + mu2;
W = sqrt(mu/r12^3);
x1 = -pi_2*r12;
x2 = pi_1*r12;
x = f(1);
y = f(2);
vx = f(3);
vy = f(4);
r1 = norm([x + pi_2*r12, y]);
r2 = norm([x - pi_1*r12, y]);
ax = 2*W*vy + W^2*x - mu1*(x - x1)/r1^3 - mu2*(x - x2)/r2^3;
ay = -2*W*vx + W^2*y - (mu1/r1^3 + mu2/r2^3)*y;
dfdt = [vx; vy; ax; ay];
end
```

[image]

Comment: I used RK4 method in my python code ,instead of RKF45 and I am getting a spiral orbit .Why is it happening?Does it matter If I use RK4?

Answer (score 1):

According to the derivation in Szebehely's *Theory of Orbits*, 1st chapter, the equations for planar, circular restricted 3BP are,

$$ 
y_1'' = y_1 + 2y_2' - \mu_2 \frac{y_1+\mu_1}{D_1} - \mu_1 \frac{y_1-\mu_2}{D_2}
$$

$$ 
y_2'' = y_2 - 2y_1' - \mu_2 \frac{y_2}{D_1} -\mu_1 \frac{y_2}{D_2}
$$

where

$$\mu_1 = \frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}$$

$$\mu_2 = 1-\mu_1$$

$$ D_1 = ((y_1+\mu_1)^2 + y_2^2 )^{3/2}$$

$$ D_1 = ((y_1-\mu_2)^2 + y_2^2 )^{3/2}$$

For certain initial values, one can obtain the Arenstorf orbit,

$y_1(0) = 0.994$, $y_1'(0)=0$, $y_2'(0) = -2.0015851063790825224053786222$

How were those initial values obtained? The answers for that will be (hopefully) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670728/finding-the-right-initial-conditions-for-a-three-body-problem-periodic-solution). Attn @dustin

Code (based on *Scientific Computing An Introduction using Maple and MATLAB* by Gander)

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate.odepack import odeint

def rhs(u,t):
    y1,y2,y3,y4 = u
    a=0.012277471; b=1.0-a;    
    D1=((y1+a)**2+y2**2)**(3.0/2);
    D2=((y1-b)**2+y2**2)**(3.0/2);
    res = [y3,\
           y4,\
           y1+2.0*y4-b*(y1+a)/D1-a*(y1-b)/D2, \
           y2-2.0*y3-b*y2/D1-a*y2/D2
           ]

    return res

t=np.linspace(0.0,17.06521656015796,10000.0)
res=odeint(rhs,[0.994,0.0,0.0,-2.00158510637908],t)
y1r,y2r,y3r,y4r=res[:, 0],res[:, 1],res[:, 2],res[:, 3]
plt.plot(y1r,y2r)
plt.text(0.1,0.1, u'Earth')
plt.text(1.0,0.1, u'Moon')
```

[image]

There is also a useful derivation [here](https://www.math.ksu.edu/reu/sumar/rebeccaspaper.pdf).

Another orbit, based on *Solving Differential Equations in R*,

```
res=odeint(rhs,[1.2,0.0,0.0,-1.049357510],t)
y1r,y2r,y3r,y4r=res[:, 0],res[:, 1],res[:, 2],res[:, 3]
plt.plot(y1r,y2r)
plt.plot(0,0,'o')
plt.plot(1,0,'o')
plt.text(0.1,0.1, u'Earth')
plt.text(1.0,0.1, u'Moon')
```

[image]