# Examples of parameter dependent ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

I would like to have some examples of simple parameter dependent ODEs. I would like the solutions to have some physical meaning. I'll give one example so it clear what I am after:

Example 1:
The [Lane-Emden equation from Astrophysics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane-Emden_equation) can be rewritten so that the first root of the solution becomes an unknown. Let $v$ be the unknown first root then the parameter-dependent ODE becomes,

$
u'' +(2/x)u' + v^2u =0, u(0)=0, u'(0)=1, u(1)=0.
$

The Lane-Emden equation model stellar formation and the parameter $v$ determines the polytropic region.

I would like to have perhaps two/three interesting examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$x''=-kx$ models simple harmonic motion. The parameter $k$ determines the period.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blog post by John Baez about a two dimensional system with a [Hopf bifurcation](http://www.azimuthproject.org/azimuth/show/Hopf+bifurcation) and applications in quantitative ecology and climate science.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

(1) Consider a beam of uniform cross section and length L, with endpoints fixed at $x = 0$ and $x = L$.  If the beam is subject to equal and opposite forces $P$ at the endpoints, then the displacement of the beam can be modeled by the eigenvalue problem

$\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} + \mu^{2}y = 0$, with $y(0) = y(L) = 0$ and $\mu^{2} = \frac{P}{EI}$.

($E$ and $I$ are both constants.  They represent Young's modulus and the moment of inertia of the cross section of the beam, respectively.)

(2) One variant of the logistic equation is

$\frac{dP}{dt} = rP(1 - \frac{P}{K})$,

which describes the  growth of a single population $P$ over time.  The parameter $r$ is the growth rate, and $K$ is the carrying capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the usual test sets for testing ODE solvers feature ODEs obtained from real-life applications. There's the [CWI-Bari test set](http://pitagora.dm.uniba.it/~testset/), test sets from [Ernst Hairer](http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/testset/testset.html) and [Jeff Cash](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~jcash/IVP_software/finaldae/readme.html), as well as the DETEST suite from Toronto (see [these](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0709052) [two](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0713075) articles for details).

One of my favorites is the restricted three-body problem ([this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54735) displays a few relevant links); it is not at once obvious that for certain preset positions of the "spaceship" that one would get a periodic orbit ("Arenstorf" orbits).