# Is there a database/collection of ODEs that are Lipschitz?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, online-resources

In order to study various ODE solvers (Forward Euler, Runge-Kutta, linear multi-step methods etc.) I would need a collection of different ODEs that are Lipschitz. Is there such a thing as an online database or similar where I can find a collection of various differential equations?

The reason is that, as of yet I have 4 differential equations where I can change the parameters in order to generate different trajectories. For example, for this ODE:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = yt^\alpha - \beta y,
$$
I can generate different trajectories by changing the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. However, doing this randomly and generating 200 trajectories, I might not always meet the Lipschitz condition. Therefore, it would be helpful to have many different dynamics, but I don't know how/where to find hundreds of ODEs? Any suggestions on how to get a collection of as many different ODEs as possible?

Comment: I was actually just wondering, should these type of questions be in the meta part, or just here?

Comment: I posted it here since there might also be a "mathematical" way of generating trajectories by adjusting the parameters whilst keeping the Lipschitz condition satisfied too

Comment: Usually you have to go to some effort to make an ODE function in the form of a computer procedure that is not Lipschitz. Remember that all smooth functions are locally Lipschitz, and all functions resulting from a non-branching computer program are at least piecewise smooth with bounded derivative, so still locally Lipschitz. /// You can search for "ODE test suite" to find collections of ODE examples that are interesting in some way. For educational purposes simple examples from population dynamics, Van der Pol oscillator and Lorenz attractor are enough to study error sources and efficiency.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59196/examples-of-parameter-dependent-odes, the answer has links to ODE IVP test suites/sets.