# Numerical divergence of some solution of the restricred three body problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

In this [question on the restricted three body problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54735/restricted-three-body-problem) are described very well the mechanics of the following system of ODEs:

\begin{cases}
y_1'' = y_1 + 2y_2' - \mu_2 \frac{y_1+\mu_1}{D_1} - \mu_1 \frac{y_1-\mu_2}{D_2} \\[6pt]
y_2'' = y_2 - 2y_1' - \mu_2 \frac{y_2}{D_1} -\mu_1 \frac{y_2}{D_2}
\end{cases}
where  $ \mu_1$ is a real number linked to the masses of the two main bodies, $\mu_2 = 1-\mu_1$ and more importanty

$$ D_1 = ((y_1+\mu_1)^2 + y_2^2 )^{3/2}$$

$$ D_1 = ((y_1-\mu_2)^2 + y_2^2 )^{3/2}$$

For theese initial values
$$y_1(0) = 0.994 \quad, \quad y_1'(0)=0 \quad, \quad  y_2'(0) = -2.0317326295573368357302057924$$

one can solve the problem and find that the orbits is a closed path after a period of
$$T = 11.124340337266085134999734047$$

(there exist other intial values for other periods for which the results are the same..)

My goal is to show this fact using some numerical methods of ODEs I've studied in the course I attended.

Firts thing first, one can see that using Euler's method the method converges only with a really small step size. In fact if I use a step $h = 0.0011$ (that is quite small) one gets as orbits a spiral

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

Using RK methods or innested (embedded ?) methods I got a more fair approximation.

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

However, I went on playing with my codes, and I thought that since the trajectory is a closed curve, doubling the period (but mantaining the step size $h$ the same) one should get the same curve traced twice and so on depending how many periods you want to go trough.

What did not surprised me is that if the solutions are not reaally precise, they start degrading:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

After two "laps" the solution is still not bad, but the velocity is really different from what it should be like (the same as the beginning). $$y(2T) = [0.9659, -0.0108, 1.0964,  -0.1590]$$

If now we want to do another lap, the spiral motion comes in again!

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

> Why does this happen? Why the spiral?

What I thought is that the equations have two singularities in $(y1, y2) = (- \mu, 0),   \quad (y1, y2) = (1- \mu, 0)$ so if one gets too close to those points we are no more in the well posture of the problem. Anyways, I can't give any motivation about the spiral motion..

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: You have to take into account that the coordinate system is rotating, so that the orbits of the massive objects become stationary. If you remove this you should get a line instead of the spiral. Essentially, the small object performed a swing-by and gained enough energy from it to land on some elongated elliptical orbit or an hyperbolic orbit, leaving the system.

Comment: That sounds as a good explanation. Thank you!

Comment: There is of course also the numerical aspect. Close to the singularities you need a much higher sampling rate. One idea here is to have the length of the step, estimated as speed times time-step, be constant. Such a strategy should increase the accuracy also without a general step-size control.